# Dividing odd numbers using assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-manipulation, operators, bit-shift

I assume that to halve an integer such as 42 using assembly language (ARM 6), a logical right shift can be used to produce 21 but could someone explain how 21 could then be halved to give me 10.5? I'm not sure what goes on "behind the scenes" to handle the fractional value.

**Update**

I guess the real question is: **is the LSR intended for division or just to shift bits to the right? If it is the latter then what is the application of Logical Shifts?**

Comment: Once you are using floating points, the computer no longer uses the normal registers (`eax`, `ebx`, etc.).  Instead it uses floating point registers, so googling around for "floating point assembly" might help you. (I've never used floating point registers, so unfortunately I can't easily make this into an answer, but good luck!)

Comment: You could switch to fixed-point and do that division in zero instructions, but then it's up to the further code to interpret that number as intended.

Answer (score 3):

An integer division cannot result in a decimal/floating point number. If you want that result you have to convert the numbers to floating point and then use a floating-point division instruction. As it turns out, floating point has a [totally different representation in binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) than integers, and as such, shifting won't work on floating point numbers.

> is the LSR intended for division or just to shift bits to the right?

Why not both? LSR is meant to shift bits as it names implies. Turns out shifting bits to the right is the same as an **unsigned integer** division by 2 (same as shifting a decimal number to the right is the same as dividing by 10).

> If it is the latter then what is the application of Logical Shifts?

There are many applications for logical shifts. [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139177/why-is-shift-register-very-important) are a couple of examples.

Comment: But I can't understand the point of doing unsigned integer division when dividing an odd number by two.

Comment: It's called an integer division, you've done it at school: the result is the quotient and the bit you just shifted is the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

LSR just shift bits to right(logical shift). if your number is unsigned, you can use LSR for div by 2. 
But if you need to div by 2 for signed numbers, you should use ASR (arithmetic shift).